# Problem with imagecreatefrompng (PHP)

Tags: php, image, png, gd, gdlib

in one of my PHP projects, imagecreatefrompng complains, that the image "is not a valid PNG file".

```
Warning: imagecreatefrompng() [function.imagecreatefrompng]:
'/.../...png' is not a valid PNG file in /.../...php on line ...
```

I'm pretty sure, the file is valid, because I can open it in any program. So I was wondering what else could cause this warning.

Does anybody know the details behind imagecreatefrompng or has had a similar problem before?

Thanks for your help,

Timo

Comment: @Timo Welcome to SO. Instead of putting SOLVED in the title of your question, click the green checkmark next to the answer below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Is** it a PNG image? Run `file` against it, or try the [fileinfo functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the fileinfo functions. I let PHP check the mime type and surprisingly enough the image was a jpg file - renaming it to .jpg solved the problem.

I guess every program I opened the file with automatically detected the mime type correctly...

Comment: I still get the same error after checking with those functions and getting the expected values: "PNG image, 873 x 361, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced"

Comment: @spuas: Then you have a different problem.

Answer (score 3):

Check this mime type of file you are going to upload by using below function:

```
mime_content_type($_FILES['product_img']['tmp_name'])
```

Image editors can often recognize file type by its contents, php might just try to use the file based on its mime-type. If it don't match then there's an error.